# What preposition is suitable in my sentence?

Tags: prepositions

My sentence is:
I took excellent in/at/for my master thesis.
Or, how can I write a better sentence?

Comment: 'Took excellent' doesn't make sense. Do you mean that  the thesis was graded as 'excellent'?

Comment: 'Took' as a verb here does not work.  None of the prepositions here make it clear what you are trying to convey.  Did you mean you received an excellent rating for your master thesis?

Comment: **I got** but better still the more formal **I obtained**. Why don't you look up these forms in a bi-lingual dictionary? Don't stop at the first definition or the first translation. Do you get "excellent" for a master thesis? What was the grade called in your mother tongue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments point out, "took" isn't the right word there. In some pursuits, like sports contests and film competitions, one can say "took first prize/place", but those are cases where it's a competition with others, and the prize is unique. The same verb can be used for lower ratings, like "second prize" and "third place", too.

In the case of a rating or grade that isn't a unique ranking, these are two possibilities for the expression:
 If "excellent" is the name of a grade, you could say

> I received/got an 'excellent' for my thesis.

If "excellent" is just a descriptive term,

> I received/got an excellent grade for my thesis.

The preposition "for" could be replaced by "on". The prepositions "in" and "at" don't fit as well.

Of course,  there are other ways to say it, such as

> My thesis was graded "excellent".

Comment: Dear Jack O'Flaherty, Thanks for your complete answer.